# Pass pseudo element selector as variable in SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I would like to know how I can pass a pseudo selector as variable in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). I have the following mixin

```
@mixin pseudoawesome($fa-symbol, $pseudo) {
  &$pseudo { // <-- here is the error
    content: $fa-symbol;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
  }
}
```

and I want to use it like:

```
@include pseudoawesome(' \f105', ':after');
```

but I cannot pass `:after` as argument for `$pseudo`. Is this somehow possible, or doesn't allow SASS using variables as selector at all?

Thanks

Comment: what you mean actually? can you explain with fiddle?

Comment: @supersize What would you like to be the expected output then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. You must write the name of variable inside the braces:

#{$yourVariable}

```
@mixin pseudoawesome($fa-symbol, $pseudo) {
  &#{$pseudo} {
    content: $fa-symbol;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
  }
}
```

EDIT: you can find this information here:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_

Just search with chrome: "If you want to use"

The section didn't have the anchor tags.